# How to make a phonegap mobile app from SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, sails.js

I've been learning to use NodeJS and SailsJS just this day and now I have a created a basic web app with user signup and list system.

It is basically almost exactly the same as this:
http://activityoverlord.herokuapp.com/

Now, since I have read from the official SailsJS documentation that it could be also be on phonegap using "sails build" that will output a "www" folder.

-> https://github.com/coderaven/sails-docs/blob/master/What-Is-Sails.md

Now, all I'm seeing are the javascript in the linker folder without the views and whatnots.
I wonder how would I have exactly the same ui and functionality on phonegap that I have on my webapp.

Will I be implementing or be creating again a new ui for the mobile app and use REST to get the data from api? Or is there anything simpler i could do to have everything set up just like the one on my web app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phonegap converts clientside code (html,js,css). not serverside code, nodejs is in javascript but acts as serverside code so you cant convert it.

The most easy way would be creating rest api (very easy in sailsjs).

or if its for iphone, you can take a look at this: 
https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC