# How to Implement SailsJS + Phonegap / Cordova application

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, sails.js

Already reviewed:
[How to make a phonegap mobile app from SailsJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023380/how-to-make-a-phonegap-mobile-app-from-sailsjs) and [SailsJS to Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952010/sailsjs-to-phonegap), but did not find the real answer.
I would like to implement a project where the backend is SailsJS and the frontends are: 1) Web client; 2) PhoneGap client;

I looked at https://github.com/coderaven/sails-docs/blob/master/What-Is-Sails.md where the usage from PhoneGap / Cordova had been mentioned but, again - not a real example provided.

So I would appreciate if somebody could share a boilerplate example including Sails and PhoneGap/Cordova or at least to share some sample code.

Comment: What's the point down voting the question??? I could understand if the downvoter provides some arguments, otherwise it is just trolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending couple of days for research and trials / fails, let me share the solution that works for me.
I will split my answer in two parts:

1. SailsJS

   - For already developed SailsJS project, just execute `sails www` from your sails project folder - it will produce what is already explained here https://github.com/coderaven/sails-docs/blob/master/What-Is-Sails.md#phonegap-chrome-extensions-and-spa-friendliness
   - Please note, to rename your `assets/js/app.js` file if you have one, otherwise it will rewrite the identical `app.js` file in your PhoneGap `www/js` folder later.
   - Make sure you know the URL, where your project has been lifted - by default it is `http://localhost:1337`
2. PhoneGap / Cordova

   - Create you PhoneGap project. It will produce `www` folder inside you PhoneGap project folder.
   - Find you `www` folder in your current sails project (see point 1) and just copy its content inside your PhoneGap `www` folder.
   - Open `www/index.html` file and add the code below before closing `body` tag:

     ```
       (function onLoad() {
         var io;

         Object.defineProperty(window, 'io', {
             get: function get() {
                 return io;
             },
             set: function set(value) {
                 var sails;

                 io = value;
                 // Immediately start connecting
                 var socket = io.connect(backendURL);

                 console.log('Connecting Socket.io to Sails.js...');

                 // Attach a listener which fires when a connection is established:
                 socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

                     console.log('Socket is now connected and globally accessible as `socket`.\n');


                     // set additional socket listeners here
                 });


                 Object.defineProperty(io, 'sails', {
                     get: function get() {
                         return sails;
                     },
                     set: function set(value) {
                         sails = value;

                         sails.url = 'backendUrl';
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
       })();
     ```

of course, do not forget to enclose it in `<script>` tag and set proper value for `backendUrl` - this is your SailsJS URL.

- Compile your PhoneGap project and enjoy